# Load AdMob banner in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i've got a problem:
i tried to load a AdMob banner in a AsyncTask but is shows the error

`Method loadAd must be called from the UI thread`

First i initialized the AdView in the onCreate method of my MainActivity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdTop = new AdView(this);
        mAdTop.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        mAdTop.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("0637136C85DF244080C2A344FA8F51C8")
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
}
```

And then i called the AsyncTask with the loadAd method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        AdMobTask adMobTask = new AdMobTask();
        adMobTask.execute(mAdTop, adRequest);
}

private class AdMobTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {

        AdView adView = (AdView) args[0];
        AdRequest requester = (AdRequest) args[1];

        adView.loadAd(requester);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But even i used the args parameters it shows the error.

How can i implement the loadAd method in an AsyncTask correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it in an async task. The loadAd is already asynchronous; simply call loadAd() from your onCreate method.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)):

public void loadAd (AdRequest adRequest)
Starts loading the ad on a background thread.